# System.out.println(); Implementation

Tags: java

Can anyone here tell me how **System.out.println()** is implemented? I have tried many sites but didn't get any satisfactory answer.

Comment: Did you check the implementation of the PrintStream class?

Comment: Attach the java code in eclipse and you can navigate through

Comment: Did you look at the source ? http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/PrintStream.java#PrintStream.printf%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.Object%5B%5D%29

Comment: The source comes with the JDK; it's in `src.zip`. And of course, it's online as well as @DenysSéguret was helpful enough to demonstrate.

Answer (score 4):

In System.out.println,

- System is a final class.
- out is object of PrintStream class inside system.
- println() is a method of PrintStream

So to print something we need to call a println which is inside PrintStream class whose object is inside System class.Hence
System.out.println();

For more information refer following 
[link](http://www.javatpoint.com/q/4939/working-of-system-out-println)

Comment: so println() is an overloaded method in PrintStream class;

Comment: @NitinNandankar yes it is,there are multiple println overloaded methods with different arguments.