# System.out.println() what is the meaning?

Tags: java

this question is actually not different from
[System.out.println(); Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31113981/system-out-println-implementation)

I saw. but I know people will stumble on this post on google.

What does System.out.println() mean?

I know System is a class..
and println() is a method...
but is println() a method of out? and what is out?
I thought only classes had methods

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/System.java#System.0out

Answer (score 1):

`System.out` is an instance of the `PrintStream` class. `println` is an instance method of `PrintStream` (actually there are multiple `println` methods in that class).

You can see how `out` is declared in the `System` class:

```
public final static PrintStream out = null;
```

Comment: so System.out is an object?(intstance of PrintStream class.)

Comment: @tobash System.out is a reference to an object.

Comment: ohhh oke so out is a reference to an object... what is System then?

Comment: @tobash System is a class

Answer (score 0):

Public final class System: a class in the java.lang package

Public static final PrintStream out: the PrintStream class reference contained in the java.io package

Public void println (): PrintStream class method